# how to save file specific folder using html2pdf

Tags: php, html2pdf

```
var element = document.getElementById('canv');
            html2pdf(element, {
                margin: 0,
                filename: 'PeaceAssessment.pdf',
                image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
                html2canvas: { scale: 1, logging: true },
                jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'a4' }
                });
```

this is my code how to save file using html2pdf

Comment: Which folder do you mean ? Local or Server?  For the server just use this code in PHP file: `$html2pdf->Output('directory/file_xxxx.pdf', 'F');`

Comment: i mean server '$html2pdf->Output('directory/file_xxxx.pdf', 'F');' how to use this code on my code. because my code using js

Comment: Do you use eKoopmans code or Spipu release? Why don't use TCPDF is much easy and more flexible.

Comment: in tcpdf i didnt get image on pdf so i just use html2pdf

Comment: Did you find the solution?? im looking for something like that, thanks

Comment: I think you can only change browser's download settings and set it to your desired location.